# Send an HTTP request from a GAE Queue

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to send an HTTP request from a Google App Engine Queue using two different approaches with no luck. I get an I/O exception in both scenarios.

The first try:

```
    String parameters =  "....";
    URL url = new URL(SOME_URL"?"+parameters);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");             
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new  
                                       InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          builder.append(line);
    }
    reader.close();
```

In the second I simply used IKay Lan code: http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/29/using-asynchronous-urlfetch-on-java-app-engine/

Is there any limitation of issuing HTTP calls from Queue?

By the way, I used different URLs with different domains and all attempts failed.

Update: When I dropped the request parameters it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the parameters values were not encoded.

To solve the issue I encoded each parameter value with URLEncoder.encode

It seems to be working fine now.